# Count the Number of Occurences a Field Value Has in a Table

Tags: php, mysql, publish, field

I have a published field that has either a value of 1 or 0. I want to be able to alert the user to how many records require publishing, or are unpublished. I want to count the number of records from table testimonials where `published` is equal to `0` and output that value as

`Awaiting to be published:#with published=0`

I have this and I realize it is wrong:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testimonials WHERE published='0'");
$result=mysql_num_rows($sql);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(published=0) AS nb_unpublished,
                           SUM(published=1) AS nb_published FROM testimonials");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
echo "Records awaiting to be published:" . $result['nb_unpublished'] . '<br>';
echo "Records already published:" . $result['nb_published'] . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(published='0',1,0)) AS 'count_awaiting',
  SUM(IF(published='1',1,0)) AS 'count_publish' 
FROM testimonials

#count_awaiting is number of records with published=0 
#count_publish is number of records with published=1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is right. You also can find count of records like this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `rows` FROM `testimonials` WHERE `published`='0'");
$result=mysql_fecth_array($sql);
echo "Awaiting to be published:".$result['rows'];
```